# Permanently assign license to a user?

Tags: rtc, jazz, rational-team-concert

We have a program that synchronizes defects between RTC and another program. To do this, we have a service user in RTC that creates/modifies workitems. But this requires a contributor license and have only a few of those.

So is there a way to ensure that this service user gets a license permanently?

For the users this isnt an issue, if there arent enough contrib licenses, they use a developer license instead, but we'd rather not give this service user the more expensive dev license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the user view (for your service user), you should see in the tab "**`overview`**" a section called "**Client Access license**" (or '`CAL`').

In here, you can select the [type of license](https://jazz.net/library/article/548) you want to attribute for that user.

[image: User Editor CAL]

More details in "[Client access license management overview](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jazz.repository.web.admin.doc/topics/c_license_mgmt_over.html)".

That will link your user to one *type* of license (not to one license instance, since we are talking about *floating* license).

Comment: Ah, so there is no way to dictate that user should always have an instance of a floating license? Makes sense now that I think about it. So the only way to guarantee we will always have a valid licence is to buy one non-floating license for this user.

Comment: @Fredrik no need: as long as your user use one of the right *type* (ie not the most expensive one) of the licenses, you are good to go.